# Problems to validate a form Cake PHP

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp

I'm new on Cake PHP and I need to validate a form. I run the application and submit normally, even with fields empty.

I want to validate them with default rules used in **UsersTables.php**

I would appreciate if someone helps me.

**register.ctp**:

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Sign Up</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>

             <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Sign Up', array('class' => 'button')); ?>


        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use this validation code below located in **UsersTable.php**:

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('nome', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('nome');

        $validator
            ->email('email')
            ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('email');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('password');



        return $validator;
    }
```

I already imported Cake\Validation\Validator; I want to understand why the validation code above works with 'add' form and others.

**UsersController.php**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;


/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{



    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);

        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

            if($this->Users->save($user))
            {
                $this->Flash->success('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso');
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Flash->error('Erro no cadastro');

            }

            $this->set('user',$user);
            $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);

        }
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();

            if($user)
            {

                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comentario', 'action' => 'add']);
            }

            // Erro no Login

            $this->Flash->error('Erro de autenticação');
        }
    }




    public function alterar()
    {
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);

        if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put']))
        {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

            if($this->Users->save($user))
            {
                $this->Flash->success('Seus dados foram alterados');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Flash->error('Erro na alteração dos dados');
            }
        }
            $this->set(compact('user'));
            $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);

    }


    public function logout()
    {
        $this->Flash->success('Sessão encerrada');
       return  $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['register']);



    }





}
```

Comment: Post the controller that's handling the form submission, more than likely the `RegistersController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Sign Up</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>

             <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Sign Up', array('class' => 'button')); ?>


        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace this code with

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Sign Up</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create($user); ?>

             <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Sign Up', array('class' => 'button')); ?>


        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this in your controller's register method

```
 public function register()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

            if($this->Users->save($user))
            {
                $this->Flash->success('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso');
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Flash->error('Erro no cadastro');

            }

        }
        $this->set('user',$user);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! the validation  it's working, but I got this error on form: Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template\Users\register.ctp, line 8]. What could be?

Comment: can you add in your controller public function register(){
      $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
      if($this->request->is('post')){
         // register code
      }
      $this->set('user',$user);
}

Comment: I already added. I modified $this->set(compact('user')); to $this->set('user', $user); and I get undefined variable error.

Comment: I have updated my post please check register function in my post

Comment: Thanks, now it's working perfectly! So, the error was put $this->set('user', $user) inside if statement. Thanks again!